# Read php file without opening and closing php tags

Tags: php, tags

I have a question regarding rendering php files without php tags. Is there away to ignore the  tags?

On a clients hosted environment our php script ran fine without the the opening and closing tags, however it died on our server. Just curious if there is a setting in the php.ini for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's considered good practice to omit the *ending* PHP tag in files that contain only PHP code. The beginning PHP tag is always required, however, as it is the only indication the interpreter has about what it needs to parse.

There are likely several ways to "cheat" this, such as running the tag-less code inside of an eval() statement, but there is arguably little reason to ever do this.

Comment: Thanks for response. It worked on an environment without it being parsed by eval(), so I am curious why it ran. This is more of a environment settings question rather than coding practices.